# PHP Thumb Issue

Tags: php, wordpress

Folks, I am working on a WP site for a client that is not loading up the featured images used by the Thumbs.php script (based on TIMThumbs), I changed the ALLOW EXTERNAL SOURCE flag to False and the images the script is picking up resides in the same server ..wp-content/uploads/..

I already changed the CACHE folder and Thumbs.php permissions (guide [here](http://hiero.eu/site/wp-content/themes/widezine%20package/documentation/))
but still no luck, I am considering using a new theme since I have read that TimThumbs is disabled by server admins due to security issues. however is there a way that I can change the thumbs.php code to use another implementation so I dont have to change the theme (which takes a lot of re-work) or have the code fixed.

I am not sure if my provider has disabled the file, just assuming.

thanks

Comment: What HTTP status code are you getting when the browser tries to load them? 404, 400, 500...?

Comment: Not getting a status code, the image link is broken however when I inspect the image, it exists on the server, could be related to the Cache folder it uses to speed up loading?

Comment: Then you're getting a 400? But if you go to the image path (that the browser is calling), it loads? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, correct, the image is in the path and it loads correctly in the browser, check it out http://goo.gl/R8H03f

Comment: I tried deleting the index.html and touch file but no luck